# Why does a simple shiny app running on local open source RStudio have very variable loading times?

Tags: r, shiny

**UPDATE**

As an update to the below post I've started to run into issues with inconsistent loading speeds for simple shiny apps launched locally (i.e. not on shiny server) again.

Essentially the very simple app below sometimes does not open within an RStudio window. Sometimes it opens with a long wait time, and sometimes straight away. This is an issue because I'm working on a larger shiny project, and I of course need reliable loading times.

I have a feeling that it may be due to my network/computer configuration - but I can't figure it out.

I've recently installed the latest version of RStudio, R and Shiny (package).

Below is my sessionInfo() result:

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19         httpuv_1.4.5         lubridate_1.7.4      later_0.7.5          shinyjs_1.0
 [6] shinydashboard_0.7.1 shiny_1.1.0          gridExtra_2.3        magrittr_1.5         forcats_0.3.0
[11] stringr_1.3.1        dplyr_0.7.7          purrr_0.2.5          readr_1.1.1          tidyr_0.8.2
[16] tibble_1.4.2         ggplot2_3.1.0        tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 haven_1.1.2      lattice_0.20-35  colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0
 [7] rlang_0.3.0.1    pillar_1.3.0     glue_1.3.0       withr_2.1.2      modelr_0.1.2     readxl_1.1.0
[13] bindrcpp_0.2.2   bindr_0.1.1      plyr_1.8.4       munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.2.0     cellranger_1.1.0
[19] rvest_0.3.2      broom_0.5.0      xtable_1.8-3     scales_1.0.0     backports_1.1.2  promises_1.0.1
[25] jsonlite_1.5     mime_0.6         hms_0.4.2        digest_0.6.18    stringi_1.2.4    grid_3.5.1
[31] cli_1.0.1        tools_3.5.1      lazyeval_0.2.1   crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.2  xml2_1.2.0
[37] assertthat_0.2.0 httr_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.8   R6_2.3.0         nlme_3.1-137     compiler_3.5.1

---

I'm relatively new to Shiny apps and can't get my app to work locally. I used the template before:

```
ui <- fluidPage("Hello World")

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I could get this to work, deploying a window displaying "Hello World" both in a local R window and in a browser window.

I've since updated R's packages and I cannot get it to work. RStudio deploys a local window which is greyed out (not displaying "Hello World") and the browser window now claims the page cannot be found.

The RStudio console says:

```
Listening on http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX
```

No other error messages are displayed. Any help would be appreciated. Most message boards start with "My app works locally but..." so research hasn't helped.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code! We can't help you if you don't let us see if there's a problem with your code. Also, you specify that the app is not working locally. Do you mean that it **does** work from the server? Or does it just not work at all?

Comment: Your code, after loading the shiny package, works fine for me. Maybe provide your `sessionInfo()`? Also, when you say "local window" do you mean in a browser window? What browser? Can you see it in the Rstudio in the viewer pane?

Comment: Apologies for not providing that information! Turns out it did work if restarted my computer. I tried to recreate the error but now can't. It works fine now.

Comment: When I did have the error, it couldn't work at all, from server or my RStudio window (what I meant by "local window"), and by browser window I meant IE. At the time I couldn't see it in the RStudio viewer pane.

Comment: Hi guys - I've provided updated info into the question. I'm not even attempting to get the app working on Shiny Server yet. It just appears to load with very inconsistent loading times.